# Security There is a Hyperlink in my GridView

Tags: asp.net, security, gridview

There is a page in my company that contains only a GridView with some data

Today i saw this text in one of the cells (i changed a little to show to you)

```
[div style="display:none"]discount online BLABLABLA[a href="http://www.[randonURL].net/page/[randompage].aspx"]click[/a] new prescription     coupon[/div]
```

I searched this text and somehow, someone inserted this in my database

How he made that?...what i can do about it?

Comment: use Encode / Decode methods before inserting values; you can also Validations at page level to raise errors when someone inputs this text

Comment: How i do that?...sorry i have no idea how to start

Comment: try keeping ValidateRequest="true" in your Page directive to prevent anyone entering HTML data in the forms;

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a classic case of SQL injection.  There are a number of things you can do to prevent it.  Here are a few.  I would suggest reading up on it though.

1. On your database methods always use parameterized SQL, stored procedures or an ORM.  Never use dynamic SQL.  In the rare case you have to, there are ways of protecting that too.  But that is a fairly long discussion.
2. Always encode user input. For JavaScript use the encodeURI() method. On the server side use the HtmlDecode() method.
3. Never show error details in the public domain.  This gives hackers clues they can use.